# How to access My.Resources from a razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I have a razor .vbhtml view and would like to use string resources normally accessible via My.Resources. Seems like I can only get to My.Computer, My.Log and couple other namespaces from the view, but not My.Resources. I've tried changing access modifier to public and adding @Imports, neither worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add a `Messages.resx` file to your project. In the properties of this file in the solution explorer set `Custom Tool = PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`. Now inside the view you can directly access resources:

```
@Imports AppName.My.Resources

<div>@Messages.Foo</div>
```

And here's a screenshot containing all you need:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was using `PublicVbMyResourcesResXFileCodeGenerator` which generates Module, the above generates a class with shared properties. I also had to change custom tool namespace to `My` otherwise it would break all other references to `My.Resources` in my existing code.