# Use an internal class in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an internal class present in the `Web.Properties` as a setting class `Settings.settings`.Now I want to use its properties of Settings class in the razor view (.cshtml file)of in mvc 4

The following code is of the setting file (auto generated)

```
[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "10.0.0.0")]
internal sealed partial class UIMessagesSettings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

    private static UIMessagesSettings defaultInstance = ((UIMessagesSettings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new UIMessagesSettings())));

    public static UIMessagesSettings Default {
        get {
            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }

    [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("An error occured while loading grid data.")]
    public string GridErrorMsg {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["GridErrorMsg"]));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to use the GridErrorMsg property in the razor view (.cshtml)
I have tried using the following code

```
@Properties.UIMessagesSettings.Default.GetType()
```

but it says UIMessagesSettings can't be accessed as it is an internal class.Any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should either make your class public or compile your views in same assembly

Also you can use "internal friendly"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx
if your views are compiled in separate assembly

If you do not compile views in single library you can not use internal class there because runtime compiles them to separate assembly and thi assembly will not see internal classes from others

If you really need it, you shall change the generator if possible

Comment: The settings class is auto-generated so can't either the assembly or make it public

Comment: But why you want to use Settings file to show some text labels. I thought Resources are designed for that?

Comment: But the resource file also has an internal class so how to use it in razor view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603050/how-to-access-my-resources-from-a-razor-view

Comment: yes i was looking at the same thing i'll have to check it out for mvc 4 thanks for help

Comment: got the solution for setting file there is a access modifier setting in the class which can change it to public

Comment: How do you compile your views into the same assembly?